# How to send data to a popover being created programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a popover for dynamic cells in an iOS tableview, and I'm a little stuck. Apparently, storyboard segues cannot be used with dynamic cells, so I have to do this programmatically. I have a normal ViewController class with the property as follows:

SOCommandPopup.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SOCommand.h"
@protocol ReturnCommand <NSObject>
@required
-(void)getCommand:(SOCommand*)command;
@end
@interface SOCommandPopup : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong)SOCommand* command;
@property (strong,nonatomic)id<ReturnCommand>delegate ;  
@end
```

It contains a protocol which is used by another view controller (the one that invokes it), to get data entered in the popover.

Popover container ViewController

```
-(void)createPopoverWith:(NSIndexPath*)commandIndex
{
    SOCommandPopup* newPopup = [[SOCommandPopup alloc]init];
    editCommandPopup = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:newPopup];
    editCommandPopup.popoverContentSize = newPopup.preferredContentSize;
    if(commandIndex)
    {
        newPopup.command = [_serverModuleCommands objectAtIndex:commandIndex.row];
    }
    else if(!commandIndex)
    {
        NSLog(@"test"); //this fires, when I pass nil 
        newPopup.command = nil;
                [editCommandPopup presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.btn_addButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    }

}
```

The `SOCommandPopup` class will construct itself based on the `command` property sent to it. So I want to be able to invoke `[self createPopoverWith:someCommand]` in the container. However, I don't know how to set its property since it is just a `UIPopoverController` and not a `SOCommandPopup`.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

~Carpetfizz

EDIT: For the sake of testing I'm passing `nil` into `createPopoverWith:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is only one way to programmatically instantiate a view controller that you're styling with the storyboard (which you said you're trying to do).

```
SDCommandPopup *newPopup = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"some_identifier"];
newPopup.command = command;
// then present the viewcontroller however you want
```

And the following image shows where you add the identifier in the storyboard.

[image: storyboard example]